# Build cannot be Generated on Raspberry Pi Pico + not recognized as internal and external error

Tags: gcc, cmake, raspberry-pi-pico

I was trying to build files from pico-examples but due to no recognition of path it throws the error. I cross checked path everywhere, environment variable, extension settings but can't seem to find the source of error.

```
    [build] Starting build
    [proc] Executing command: D:\Softwares-(installed)\Pico-Tools\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE --build d:/Pico/pico-examples/build --config Debug --target all -j 18 --
    [build] Scanning dependencies of target bs2_default
    [build] [  0%] Creating directories for 'ELF2UF2Build'
    [build] [  0%] Creating directories for 'PioasmBuild'
    [build] [  0%] Building ASM object pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/compile_time_choice.S.obj
    [build] 'D:\Softwares-' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    [build] operable program or batch file.
    [build] 'D:\Softwares-' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    [build] operable program or batch file.
    [build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [blink\CMakeFiles\ELF2UF2Build.dir\build.make:106: blink/elf2uf2/src/ELF2UF2Build-stamp/ELF2UF2Build-mkdir] Error 1
    [build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [adc\dma_capture\CMakeFiles\PioasmBuild.dir\build.make:106: adc/dma_capture/pioasm/src/PioasmBuild-stamp/PioasmBuild-mkdir] Error 1
    [build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:4279: adc/dma_capture/CMakeFiles/PioasmBuild.dir/all] Error 2
    [build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    [build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:4144: blink/CMakeFiles/ELF2UF2Build.dir/all] Error 2
    [build] [  0%] Linking ASM executable bs2_default.elf
    [build] 'D:\Softwares-' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
    [build] operable program or batch file.
    [build] mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [pico-sdk\src\rp2_common\boot_stage2\CMakeFiles\bs2_default.dir\build.make:96: pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/bs2_default.elf] Error 1
    [build] mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:4039: pico-sdk/src/rp2_common/boot_stage2/CMakeFiles/bs2_default.dir/all] Error 2
    [build] mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:90: all] Error 2
    [build] Build finished with exit code 2
```